# Multiple table joins and using only one blade for results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I'm using Laravel 5.4 to create a project.
I'm using these 3 tables with that relation.

[image: image description]

At my home page I'm doing a `foreach` on 9 elements. And everything is working fine there.

[image: image description]

This is my route:

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get("/game/{id_g}","HomeController@openGameHtml");
Route::get("/game/{id_g}","HomeController@openGameCss");
```

My controller:

```
public function openGameHtml($chosenGame, Request $request)
    {
        $chosenGame = DB::table('games')
        ->join('listhtmlgames', 'games.id_g', '=', 'listhtmlgames.id_g')
        ->select('games.*', 'listhtmlgames.*')
        ->where('listhtmlgames.id_g', $chosenGame)->get();

        //var_dump($chosenGame);
        dd($chosenGame);
        //print_r($chosenGame);

        return view('openGame', compact('chosenGame'));
    }

   public function openGameCss($chosenGame, Request $request)
    {
        $chosenGame = DB::table('games')
        ->join('listcssgames', 'games.id_g', '=', 'listcssgames.id_g')
        ->select('games.*', 'listcssgames.*')
        ->where('listcssgames.id_g', $chosenGame)->get();
        var_dump($chosenGame);
        //($chosenGame);
        //print_r($chosenGame);

        return view('openGame', compact('chosenGame'));
    }
```

And i'm trying to foreach multiple results at one blade. Here:

```
 @foreach($chosenGame as $item)
    <li><a href="">
    {{$item->name}}</a></li>
@endforeach
```

The problem is always one of these two function in controller are working in my last foreach. I can't find a way to make my blade working for these 2 functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the same variable in both functions, and in your @foreach you are looping thru that variable.
Set different variables and pass them to the view, once in the view loop thru each variable extracting the properties you need.

Change the:

return view('openGame', compact('openGameHtml'));

and

return view('openGame', compact('chosenGameCss'));

in the view use @foreach with each variable name.

The issue is that you want to extract different collections of results with the same variable which is not possible, you need to pass two different variables. Post result if you have any inconvenience so we can provide a accurable answer. Otherwise go to the [Official Documentation - Passing Data to view](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#passing-data-to-views)